# Using LIKE and equal in SQL statement

Tags: mysql

Is there something wrong with this SQL statement?
Specifically, in the "LIKE ? AND deck_id = ?" part.

```
"SELECT * FROM cards WHERE 
  card_one LIKE ? OR card_two LIKE ? OR card_three LIKE ? 
  AND deck_id = ? OR deck_id = ? OR deck_id = ? OR deck_id = ?
  OR deck_id = ? OR deck_id = ? OR deck_id = ?"
```

It searches for card_one and card_two properly, but not the third. If I take card_three out, then card_two does not work. Which leads me to believe that something in that area isn't right.

Can you use LIKE with AND in this way?

Desired results are

```
"SELECT * FROM cards WHERE (card1-3 LIKE ?) AND (Deck_id = decks_array)"
```

if that makes sense.

Comment: You probably should add some parenthesis around your clauses.  Mixing `OR` and `AND` doesn't do what you think.

Comment: Use some parantheses:
`(card_one LIKE ? OR card_two LIKE ? OR card_three LIKE ?)`
`AND`
`(deck_id = ? OR deck_id = ? OR deck_id = ? OR deck_id = ?
  OR deck_id = ? OR deck_id = ? OR deck_id = ?")`

Comment: P.S. Replace `deck_id = ? OR deck_id = ? OR deck_id = ?` with `deck_id IN (?,?,?)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"SELECT * FROM cards WHERE 
  (card_one LIKE ? OR card_two LIKE ? OR card_three LIKE ?) 
  AND deck_id in (id1,id2,id3)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `(...)` around your conditions like so:

```
"SELECT * FROM cards WHERE 
 ( card_one LIKE ? OR card_two LIKE ? OR card_three LIKE ? )
 AND ( deck_id = ? OR deck_id = ? OR deck_id = ? OR deck_id = ?
       OR deck_id = ? OR deck_id = ? OR deck_id = ? )"
```